# Firebase realtime database: what is the prefeable way to organize AddValueListener part?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app using Firebase realtime databse. The code inside `onDataChange` is getting fat. For example there are some if statements indside the part and it nested. I'm wondering if there's a preferable way to organize this part. I want to separate the part that handle with Firebase from `Activity`.

```
mNode.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             //this part is getting fat
             if (dataSnapshot.haschild("aValue")) {
                  ...
                  if (dataSnapshot.
                     ...
                  if (dataSnapshot.
                     ...
            } else {...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a preferable way to organize this part.

The way you are using those if statements look good to me. You are using them inside the callback which is the correct way of getting data from asynchronous methods. If you want, you can create a method and pass the `DataSnapshot` object as an argument and move the entire logic in that method. But in my opinions there is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep my approach.